# Display bookings date time in Woocommerce admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-bookings

In Woocommerce with Woocommerce Bookings, I have the following to add the booking details in WooCommerce order preview, below each order item:

```
function get_booking_id_from_order_item( $item_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_booking_order_item_id' AND meta_value = %d", $item_id ) );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns', 'filter_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns', 10, 2 );
function filter_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns( $columns, $order ) {
    $first_column = $columns['product'];
    unset($columns['product']);

    return array_merge( array('product2' => $first_column ), $columns );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_product2', 'filter_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_product2', 10, 4 );
function filter_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_product2( $html, $item, $item_id, $order ) {
    $product = is_callable( array( $item, 'get_product' ) ) ? $item->get_product() : null;

    $html   .= wp_kses_post( $item->get_name() );

    if ( $product ) {
        $html .= '<div class="wc-order-item-sku">' . esc_html( $product->get_sku() ) . '</div>';
    }

    if ( $booking_id = get_booking_id_from_order_item( $item_id ) ) :
    $booking      = get_wc_booking( $booking_id );
    $date_format  = wc_date_format();
    $date_format .= ' ' . wc_time_format(); // ==> Comment this line if time is not needed in bookingstart date format

    ob_start(); // Start buffering
    ?>
    <div class="wc-booking-summary">
        <strong class="wc-booking-summary-number">
        <?php printf( __( 'Booking #%d', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), $booking_id ); ?>
            <span class="status-<?php echo $booking->get_status(); ?>"><?php echo ucfirst( $booking->get_status() ); ?></span>
        </strong>
        <div class="wc-booking-summary-list">
        <li>
        <?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'wc_bookings_summary_list_date', date_i18n( $date_format, $booking->get_start() ), $booking->get_start(), $booking->get_end() ) );
        if ( wc_should_convert_timezone( $booking ) ) :
            /* translators: %s: timezone name */
            echo esc_html( sprintf( __( 'in timezone: %s', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), $booking->get_local_timezone() ) );
        endif;
        ?>
        </li>
        <?php if ( $resource = $booking->get_resource() ) : ?>
            <li>
            <?php
            $label = method_exists( $resource, 'get_label' ) ? $resource->get_label() : __('Resource', 'woocommerce-bookings');
            /* translators: 1: label 2: resource name */
            echo esc_html( sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), $label, $resource->get_name() ) );
            ?>
            </li>
        <?php endif;

        if ( $product && $product->has_persons() ) {
            if ( $product->has_person_types() ) {
                $person_types  = $product->get_person_types();
                $person_counts = $booking->get_person_counts();

                if ( ! empty( $person_types ) && is_array( $person_types ) ) {
                    foreach ( $person_types as $person_type ) {

                        if ( empty( $person_counts[ $person_type->get_id() ] ) ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        ?>
                        <li><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( '%s: %d', $person_type->get_name(), $person_counts[ $person_type->get_id() ] ) ); ?></li>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <li>
                <?php
                /* translators: 1: person count */
                echo esc_html( sprintf( __( '%d Persons', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), array_sum( $booking->get_person_counts() ) ) );
                ?>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    $html .= ob_get_clean(); // Set back buffered content
    endif;

    $meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( '' );

    if ( $meta_data ) {
        $html .= '<table cellspacing="0" class="wc-order-item-meta">';

        foreach ( $meta_data as $meta_id => $meta ) {
            if ( in_array( $meta->key, $hidden_order_itemmeta, true ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $html .= '<tr><th>' . wp_kses_post( $meta->display_key ) . ':</th><td>' . wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $meta->display_value ) ) . '</td></tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

How to display the booking date and time (not the order date and time) in in the woocommerce admin orders list under the billing_address column?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to display the bookings date and time in the woocommerce admin orders list under the billing_address column:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'display_bookings_datetime_orders_admin_list', 20, 2 );
function display_bookings_datetime_orders_admin_list( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'billing_address' === $column ) {
        global $post, $the_order;

        $order = is_a($the_order, 'WC_Order') ? $the_order : wc_get_order( $post->ID ); // Get WC_Order Object

        $date_format  = wc_date_format();
        $date_format .= ' ' . wc_time_format(); // ==> Comment this line if time is not needed in booking start date format

        $datetimes    = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();

            if ( ! $product->is_type('booking') ) {
                continue;
            }
            $booking_ids = WC_Booking_Data_Store::get_booking_ids_from_order_item_id( $item_id );

            // Loop through booking Ids in the order
            foreach ( $booking_ids as $booking_id ) {
                $booking = get_wc_booking( $booking_id );

                $datetimes[] = esc_html( apply_filters( 'wc_bookings_summary_list_date', date_i18n( $date_format, $booking->get_start() ), $booking->get_start(), $booking->get_end() ) );
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty($datetimes) ) {
            // Output html
            echo '<ul class="wc-booking-summary-list"><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $datetimes) . '</li></ul>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.