# Display Booking Start / End Date in WooCommerce Admin Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-bookings

I swiftly went through five other posts on Stack Overflow in an attempt to modify the code for the correct answer. [Some of them looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099814/1927168), but none of them yielded the desired results. Consequently, I decided to begin from scratch.

My objective is to:

- Add column on the WooCommerce Orders page.
- Visit mywebsite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order and see column with dates
- Include booking start and booking end dates in that column.
- *there is always just one booking per order*

Here's the code I've developed thus far that adds the column to the order page:

```
// Add custom column to WooCommerce admin orders page
function custom_add_booking_dates_column($columns) {
    // Add the custom column after the "Order Actions" column
    $columns['booking_dates'] = __('Booking Dates', 'text-domain');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_add_booking_dates_column');

// Populate the custom column with "Testing" text
function custom_populate_booking_dates_column($column) {
    global $post;
    
    if ($column === 'booking_dates') {
        // Output the text you want to display in the custom column
        echo 'Testing';
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_populate_booking_dates_column');
```

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Editing wp-config and increasing memory
- Turning on debug to solve (was getting `wc_booking_order_has_bookings` error)
- Loading WooCommerce and WooCommerce Bookings in child theme function
- Copying some files from plugin into child theme and editing the `/woocommerce-bookings/order/admin/booking-display.php` and `booking-summary-list.php` files

I also tried taking all the code examples I found on SO and having GPT analyze and write a function but everything that produced too, was no good.

```
// Add custom column to WooCommerce admin orders page
function custom_add_booking_dates_column($columns) {
    // Add the custom column after the 'order_actions' column
    $columns['booking_dates'] = __('Booking Dates', 'text-domain');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_add_booking_dates_column');

// Populate the custom column with data
function custom_booking_dates_column_content($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column == 'booking_dates') {
        // Retrieve booking dates for the order (replace this with your own logic)
        $booking_dates = get_post_meta($post_id, '_booking_dates', true);

        // Display the booking dates
        echo esc_html($booking_dates);
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_booking_dates_column_content', 10, 2);



add_action('after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_setup');

function child_theme_setup() {
    // Load WooCommerce
    add_theme_support('woocommerce');
    
    // Load WooCommerce Bookings
    add_theme_support('woocommerce-bookings');
}



// Add custom column to WooCommerce admin orders page
function add_custom_column_to_orders_page($columns) {
    // Add a new column called "Booking Dates" after the "Order Total" column
    $columns['booking_dates'] = __('Booking Dates', 'text-domain');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_custom_column_to_orders_page', 20);

// Populate custom column with Booking Start and Booking End dates
function populate_custom_column_content($column) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ($column === 'booking_dates') {
        $order_id = $post->ID;

        // Check if the order has booking data
        if (wc_booking_order_has_bookings($order_id)) {
            $booking_data = wc_get_order($order_id)->get_items('booking');
            
            // Loop through each booking item (there may be multiple bookings in one order)
            foreach ($booking_data as $item_id => $booking_item) {
                $booking_start = date_i18n(wc_date_format(), strtotime($booking_item['Start']));
                $booking_end = date_i18n(wc_date_format(), strtotime($booking_item['End']));

                // Display Booking Start and End dates for each booking
                echo '<strong>' . __('Booking #', 'text-domain') . $booking_item['Booking ID'] . '</strong><br>';
                echo __('Start Date:', 'text-domain') . ' ' . esc_html($booking_start) . '<br>';
                echo __('End Date:', 'text-domain') . ' ' . esc_html($booking_end) . '<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo __('No booking data', 'text-domain');
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'populate_custom_column_content');
```

Comment: ChatGPT generated code is prohibited and completely banned here in Stack OverFlow.

Answer (score 1):

For [WooCommerce Bookings](https://woocommerce.com/documentation/products/extensions/woocommerce-bookings/) enabled plugin, to display booking items start/end dates in admin product list on a new column, use the following:

```php
// Add custom column to WooCommerce admin orders page
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_custom_column_booking_dates', 20 );
function add_custom_column_booking_dates( $columns ) {
    $columns['booking_dates'] = __('Booking Dates', 'text-domain');
    return $columns;
}

// Custom column displayed content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'display_custom_column_booking_dates_content', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_column_booking_dates_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'booking_dates' === $column ) {
        global $post, $the_order;

        $order = is_a($the_order, 'WC_Order') ? $the_order : wc_get_order( $post->ID ); // Get WC_Order Object
        $found = false;

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $booking_ids = WC_Booking_Data_Store::get_booking_ids_from_order_item_id( $item_id );

            if ( $booking_ids ) {
                $found = true;
                foreach ( $booking_ids as $booking_id ) {
                    $booking       = new WC_Booking( $booking_id ); // Get booking object
                    $booking_start = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $booking->get_start());
                    $booking_end   = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $booking->get_end());
                
                    // Display Booking Start and End dates for each booking
                    echo '<strong>' . __('Booking #', 'text-domain') . $booking_id . '</strong><br>';
                    echo __('Start Date:', 'text-domain') . ' ' . esc_html($booking_start) . '<br>';
                    echo __('End Date:', 'text-domain') . ' ' . esc_html($booking_end) . '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
        if ( ! $found ) {
            echo __('No data', 'text-domain');
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your proactive effort in providing the best solution. Moving forward, I'll refrain from using GPT-related content. However, I wanted to ensure I explored all available options before posting here. Regarding your code, I'm encountering an issue where it's returning "No booking data," despite my knowledge that booking data exists. This information is evident in the email confirmation, as I can clearly see the dates. I even attempted to incorporate this code into the functions.php file and used the Snippets plugin, creating a snippet with the same code, but the issue persists.

Comment: Incidentally, I've delved into your previous posts and have made an attempt with all the provided code snippets as well. Unfortunately, I haven't had any success in displaying the order dates anywhere, whether it's in the preview popup, on the view order page, or any other relevant location. I think I'll try disabling every other plugin and see if that helps. I turned on debug and didn't see any errors either. ‍♂️

Comment: I just tested my code, and it works perfectly (see on my answer the screenshot). So something else is making trouble, or you are using another booking plugin that is not the official WooCommerce one.

Comment: Yes, this situation is quite unusual. I've gone ahead and deactivated all plugins except for Bookings v2.0.3 and WooCommerce v8.1.1 , switched to the default theme, and tested it, but I'm still not getting any dates returned. It's perplexing. I was using PHP version 8.1, and i swapped to 7.4 but that didn't work. The screenshot you provided is precisely what I need.  I just peaked at WC > Status > Tools > Logs to see if I could find something else... slowly losing my mind... thanks for the help!